# Outlook message display

Tags: c#, asp.net, outlook

I use below given code to display outlook message.

```
  Outlook.MailItem oMailItem = (Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
  oMailItem.To = toValue;
  oMailItem.Subject = SubjectValue;
  oMailItem.Body = BodyValue;          
  oMailItem.Display(true);
```

The above code is run on the local system. But If I deployed the code on the server Then the client system not open outlook message on the client system. 
Please help me.

Comment: Welcome :) Next time when you post code, select the code and press Ctrl+K or press the curly braces to format the selection as code.

Comment: WHY would you want to do such a thing? open outlook using asp.net on a remote server? that will probably block your application unless you intend to actually SEND AN EMAIL using outlook - and this is NOT the appropriate way to do such things.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse it won't open Outlook on the client - this code runs SERVER SIDE which means it will try to open up Outlook on the SERVER, not the CLIENT.

EDIT:

If you want to open the Default mail client on the *client's* side, you can use the `mailto:` directive:

for example,

```
<a href="mailto:john@email.com?subject=This is my subject&body=This part contains the body of the message" />
```

Is a link that once pressed, will open the default mail client with the Subject and Body of the message.
You can achieve the same using Javascript.

Comment: Would u help me to open outlook message on the client.
Now I have a code to open outlook message on the client is

     <a href="#" onclick=window.open{'mailto:sumitkmr558@gmail.com','','',''}> click</a>
But This is not good for me. Because  I have a message data from the database on the click button.
Pls help me

Comment: and MY mailto is a variable. pls help